# If $f(\frac{x}{x+1})=x^2$ then what is $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions

Feeling puzzled. If $f(\frac{x}{x+1})=x^2$, then what is $f(x)$?

Comment: HINT:  Set $\dfrac x{x+1}=y\iff x=?$

Comment: Let $y = x/(1+x)$. Solve for $x$. Then $f(y) = ?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$ is an invertible function. So when $$f(g(x))=x^2$$ then letting $x$ be swapped out with $g^{-1}(x)$ gives $$f(x)=\left(g^{-1}(x)\right)^2=\left(\frac{x}{-x+1}\right)^2$$ This is valid for all $x\neq1$ since any such $x$ is in the range of $g$. I suppose you could additionally define a value for $f(1)$ and that would not contradict the original relation.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :** Put $\displaystyle \frac{x}{x+1}=y$. Find $x$ in terms of $y$ and put.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Substitute $$x=\frac{-1}{t-1}-1=\frac{-t}{t-1}$$

Notice $$\frac{x}{1+x}=t$$